# Getting data from JTable for selected JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have the code below for putting check box in every row of table. How to get the value of selected check box? Like say I need the values of company names of the selected check boxes...

```
package JavaApplication1;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JavaApplication1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public JavaApplication1() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50), false},
            {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), true},
            {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), true},
            {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00), false}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /*@Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }*/
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return Integer.class;
                    case 3:
                        return Double.class;
                    default:
                        return Boolean.class;
                }
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JavaApplication1 frame = new JavaApplication1();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewThompson I will follow it from next time and thanks for editing

Comment: *"I will follow it from next time"* Now *that* is good to hear.  *"and thanks for editing"*  You're welcome.  Glad you got a solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
     Boolean isChecked = Boolean.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());

     if (isChecked) {
        //get the values of the columns you need.
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Row %s is not checked \n", i);
    }
}
```